# Exclude a few tables from logical replication in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, replication, database-administration

As in MySQL we have option to exclude a few table from replication (or include). But in postgres, we have the option to add tables to publication/subscription but if we have like 1000 tables and we want to exclude 2 tables out of these, do we have this option anyways? So instead of adding 998, I just exclude 2

Comment: If you are replicating 998 tables, how much difference will it make to not replicate 2 tables ?

Comment: It was just an example
One use case can be I don't want 2 very large tables to be replicated. Anyways don't go to numbers. I just want to exclude tables from replication

Comment: This is actually a totally valid question - Even if you only have 30 tables it's still an additional maintenance task to have to always remember to include tables rather than excluding. Opt out vs opt in is a common pattern throughout programming.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that with 1000 tables your schema is weirdly designed.

Anyway, in PostgreSQL we have `psql` and its `\gexec`, which can be used to automatize the task.